# Sass number precision and webpack

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, sass, webpack

I'm using bootstrap 3 with sass and it appears that I'm having an issue with the default number precision of 5. However, I can't find a way to increase this number precision. Here's my webpack configuration for the loaders.

```
{
    test: /\.scss$/,
    exclude: /node_modules/,
    loaders: ['raw-loader', 'sass-loader']
}
```

The actual problem I'm having is with the alignment of an input group.

[image: Input group 1 pixel off]

As you can see above, it's 1 pixel off. When I edit the precision of the line height of the element in the chrome dev tools, it lines up perfectly. The problem also occurs in safari, but not in firefox.

Comment: What's your sass and what is it compiling to? If it's all Bootstrap, could you replicate using bootply.com or a codepen.io demo?

Answer (score 1):

## Webpack 2

Webpack 2 has changed how to declare loaders usage. Here is the new syntax:

```js
use: [{
    loader: 'sass-loader',
    options: { ... },
}],
```

This is the full configuration about SCSS files.

```js
{
    test: /\.scss$/,
    use: [
        { loader: 'style-loader' },
        { loader: 'css-loader' },
        { loader: 'postcss-loader' },
        {
            loader: 'sass-loader',
            options: { precision: 8 },
        },
    ],
}
```

And this is the full configuration using ExtractTextPlugin:

```js
{
    test: /\.scss$/,
    use: ExtractTextPlugin.extract({
        use: [
            { loader: 'css-loader' },
            { 
                loader: 'postcss-loader', 
                options: { precision: 8 },
            }
        ],
        fallback: 'style-loader',
    }),
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The recommended way of doing this by defining a `sassLoader` property at the root level of your webpack config:

```
module.exports = {
  ...
  sassLoader: {
    precision: 8  // Avoid rounding errors in bootstrap styles
  }
  ...
};
```

This doesn't appear to work in webpack 2, but it looks like you can pass options as query parameters:

```
rules: [
  {
    test: /\.s?css$/,
    loader: ExtractTextPlugin.extract({
      fallbackLoader: ['style-loader'],
      loader: ['css-loader?sourceMap', 'sass-loader?sourceMap&precision=8']
    })
  }
]
```